# Get range class of Datatype property

Tags: properties, range, sparql

I have the following SPARQL query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ?p ?class ?type
 WHERE {
       ?resource ?p ?target .
       ?p rdfs:range ?class .
       ?class rdf:type ?type .
}
```

I get results only for the object properties.
If ?class = xsd:float, then rdf:type = rdfs:Datatype, right?

Why I do not receive also results for the type of data properties?

Comment: because those triples are not loaded in the triple store?

Comment: @UninformedUser if I remove the last statement i.e. ?class rdf:type ?type, I receive in ?class bindings: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer etc. 

What I wanted to get is that http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer for example, belongs to the Class rdfs:Datatype, i.e. ?type = rdfs:Datatype

Comment: and what I wanted to say is that the RDF triples for XML schema are not loaded in the dataset, those are more or less axiomatic triples.

Comment: RDFS entailment might give you those triples: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf11-mt-20140225/ : *"When using RDFS semantics, the referents of all recognized datatype IRIs can be considered to be in the class rdfs:Datatype.

"*

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you very much. I am new in ontologies that's why I am a bit confused :)